# Calling MIA / SS

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

What is the best way to tell your team that your laning opponent(s) is missing?

Should blue-ping the map that leads towards them, yellow-ping (Fall back) on top of them?

Should you stop for a moment to type [lane] mia/ss or care [lane]?

Should you say which champ is missing?

I want to make sure that my team knows that my lane is empty and that they could be in danger, but I don't want to become a pest pinging the map constantly when Twitch wants to stealth either. Assume that voice-chatting programs are unavailable. What is the general method that most players know and use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally assume people know which lane has which champion so I only say: mid mia

There are cases in which I do other things:

1. I know which way enemy champ is going - I use several pings to highlight champions path with an additional back ping if my teammates don't respond.
2. My opponent has been gone away - I say "mid still mia, prob [whichever lane is most exposed]"
3. Enemy jungler walks through my lane - "[jungler] going [direction]"

Comment: I always get scared to stop and type because I don't want a Morgana or Blitzcrank to land a skill shot on me that could end my life, and I don't want to lose valuable early game last hits to sit under turret to call mia. I often get complained at if I ping the map because "nobody pings anymore" or "I don't have sound on"

Answer (score 1):

play with people who have great map awareness and notices when a champ is not on the minimap would be the best.  Short of that, I find pinging likely paths a mia champ might go for ganking or if you notice a champ passing through a ward pinging that works too, especially at lower elo levels.  Typing in-game chat with the new alerts of item purchases just clutter things and provides no in-game sound.