# Why do they call SS in EU server and MIA in NA server

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

Why do players on the EU server say SS when an enemy is missing and on the NA server MIA?
And is there an important difference between them?

Comment: I don't know what "SS" means, but I do know that "MIA" stands for "missing in action", like soldiers.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding:

- [What does SS stand for when an opponent is missing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56530/what-does-ss-stand-for-when-an-opponent-is-missing)
- [Calling MIA / SS](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58374/calling-mia-ss)
- [What do those abbreviations mean in LoL?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol)

---

Now to the question...
There is no difference. They are the same.

SS = miSSing Or Switching Sides
Mia = Miss in Action

Both are meaning to call when your opponent is not in your line of sight. (Recal, brush, hide (eve, twitch...), etc.

Answer (score 0):

no, there really is no difference, its just like people in the USA calling Coke and Pepsi  Pop or Soda. just two different ways to say the exact same thing. MIA means missing in action, as SS stands for miSS or Stay Safe.

Answer (score 0):

like few of them have already answered what ss and mia stands for (and both meaning same). Apart from that, for me I think ss is most easy and fast way to call. Try your self, type mia and type ss 10 times each (without using warkeys) check which one is faster